# How to access GUI from TTY

Tags: 20.04, gui, tty

Ubuntu enters tty mode with itself I'm trying to go back to GUI by using `ctrl+alt` with `F1-F12` but It doesn't work. In addition, when I'm trying to update by using `sudo apt update` it gives me errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGPAI.png).

Ubuntu version:20.4

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like X level multi user mode has been disabled, for that there'll likely need to be a deep dive into error logs in /var/log, in my experience from the past that can often be part of an upgrade of Xwindows and/or device drivers if you're using very new/high end graphics hardware.

for the apt errors, it seems like your dns resolution is broken, I'd start on that with checking with 'ls -l /etc/resolv.conf' and the contents of the file.